# Visual Studio throws error while loading the solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

While try to load the projects in VS2017 i am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution.

```
           ***VcTargetsPath*** was set wrongly in the environment variable.
```